# How to integrate Angular 6 Single Page Application with FLASK architecture?

Tags: python, angular, flask

I'm using one of the Angular 6 template for frontend and using Python to do some heavier computation of images.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('./index.html')

@app.route('/api/test')
def test():
    socketio.emit('resp', {'data': 'got it!'});
    return "done"

if _name_ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

I tried integrating angular 6 template with FLASK it worked for me but on refresh of the application or by changing state it throws me following error

```
"Page not found 404"
```

Please, help with integrating the Single Page Application.

Comment: Please, send here part of your code which makes a request to `/api/test`.

Comment: I don't have problem with API requests the problem is with rendering Single Page Application views(dist folder of angular 2 and above applications)

Comment: Then, probably, you are making a `POST` request when your view accepts only `GET` requests.

Comment: no that's not the issue.
main page (landing page) works properly as soon as i start sever if i refresh or change the route it throws me 404 error

Comment: Then start your server, make a single request to your landing page and send here an output via gist or pastebin, please.